# How to start an activity if device is charging and battery level is full?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I need to start an activity when the device is charging and the battery level reaches 100% (or close to it, let's say above 95%). App being open or closed.

I can trigger a broadcast receiver when the charger is plugged in and check the battery level, but if it's not in the range I want, nothing should happen. But that's as far as I can go. I don't know how to keep monitoring it until it reaches the desired battery level without running a task on an activity. I need this to happen on the background.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the device is charging with this method

```
public static boolean isCharging(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        BatteryManager batteryManager = (BatteryManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE);
        return batteryManager.isCharging();
    } else {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, filter);
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Get battery percentage with this method

```
public static int getBatteryPercentage(Context context) {

    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, iFilter);

    int level = batteryStatus != null ? batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) : -1;
    int scale = batteryStatus != null ? batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1) : -1;

    float batteryPct = level / (float) scale;

    return (int) (batteryPct * 100);
}
```

then check

```
if(isCharging(getContext()) && getBatteryPercentage(getContext()) == 100){
//start your activity here
}
```

Comment: Ok. There I got. But what if the battery is not charged? How do I keep waiting? I forgot to say, I need to use receivers, it's supposed to happen with or without the app being open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Job Dispatcher, in code you can specify some constraints such as charging or network status. Check out the link https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#scheduling-a-more-complex-job

Comment: Charging and network status are not enough. I need battery full.

Comment: If so you can use Ege's answer to check the battery level